# How to create a form with 2 select tag, adding element from this select to another select, and handle form submission?

Tags: javascript, html, picklist

I would like to create a form like this, which I can add/remove individual/all element between **Available** and **Seleteted** select tag.

[image]

When hitting the submit button, form will submit information from **Selected** to servlet backend process.

So my question are:

1. How to create above form, binding data to **Available**, handling 4 button to move element?
2. How to send all data from **Selected** to server when hitting submit button?

Comment: Looking into this.

Comment: @RohitGaikwad I'm sorry, this what?

Comment: I'm having a look into this question.means writng/analyzing the problem statement.

Comment: once you have selected some values from available group to selected group, and later on the user tries to select the same value from available group (I.e duplicate values). Do you want to avoid duplicates as well?

Comment: @RohitGaikwad Well, I'm thinking about remove item from available group after adding to selected group, that would avoid duplicate item.

Comment: Ok, will do that also.

Comment: When you hit the submit button of the above form, did you need the values say, one, two, three associated with group one,group two, group three options respectively? Or the labels  group one,group two, group three  as values

Comment: @RohitGaikwad Yes, the value will be the groupId, the display content will be groupName.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123340/discussion-between-rohit-gaikwad-and-thong-vo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming you can use jquery

I have two selects `multiselect1` and `choosenItems`

Below I copy selected items from `multiselect1`

```
var options = $('select.multiselect1 option:selected').sort().clone();

for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    $('select.choosenItems').append(options[i]);
}
```

So for my addAll function

```
$('.addAll').on('click', function() {

    var options = $('select.multiselect1 option').sort().clone();

    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        $('select.choosenItems').append(options[i]);
    }
}
```

For submitting to my servlet I am also using jquery, and again doing

```
    $(".choosenItems option").each(function() {
        chosenStr = chosenStr + "&chItems=" + $(this).val();
    }); 

    loadUrl = "myServlet?" +  event + '&' + chosenStr;
```

and then a normal jquery ajax call

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    async: true,  
    url: loadUrl,  
    success: function(data){ 
            // something                        
    }  
});
```

Comment: Thanks. 
Some question:
1. How to remove selected item after append it to the other select tag?
2. Is it possible to submit all information from **Selected** to servlet by one parameter?

Comment: to remove `$('select.multiselect1 option:selected').remove();`

Comment: As for the one parameter, you could build up a String with some type of delimiter e.g. `|` and then call it as `loadUrl = "myServlet?" +  event + '&chosenItems=' + chosenStr;`

Comment: Got it.
I would like to keep the element position after add/remove it, how to do that?

Comment: That I do not know

Answer (score 1):

The technologies used for solving the above query are HTML, CSS, JavaScript and Servlets.

Javascript validation is also applied, so as to avoid unselected items

Please find the below action servlet code:

```
package com.formselection;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@WebServlet("/FormSelection")
public class FormSelection extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = null;
    try {

        out=response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        String[] selected = request.getParameterValues("s_groups");
        if (selected != null) {
            out.println("Below are your Selected options: ");
            for (String s : selected) {
                out.println("<br/> " + s);
            }
        }else{
            out.println("You have not Selected any option");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
 }

}
```

Please find the below code for formSelection.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Form Selection</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="FormSelection" method="post">
    <div id="available_groups" style="float: left;margin: 10px;">
        Available Groups<br /> 
        <select multiple name="a_groups" id="a_groups" style="position:relative; border: 2px solid black; margin: 5px; padding: 5px;" size="6">
            <option value="Group one">Group one</option>
            <option value="Group two">Group two</option>
            <option value="Group three"> Group three </option>
            <option value="Group four">Group four</option>
            <option value="Group five">Group five</option>
            <option value="Group six">Group six</option>
            <option value="Group seven">Group seven</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="select_buttons" style="position: relative; float: left;" >
        <button type="button" name="multiple_select" style="margin-top: 35px;margin-bottom: 5px;" onclick="getMultipleSelectedValues()">=></button><br/>
        <button type="button" name="single_select" style="margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;" onclick="getSingleSelectedValue()">-></button><br/>
        <button type="button" name="single_deselect" style="margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;" onclick="setSingleDeSelectedValue()"><-</button><br/>
        <button type="button" name="multiple_deselect" style="margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;" onclick="setMultipleDeSelectedValue()"><=</button><br/>
    </div>
    <div style="position: relative; float: left;margin: 10px;">
        Selected Groups<br /> 
        <select multiple name="s_groups" id="s_groups" style="position:relative; border: 2px solid black; margin: 5px; padding: 5px;" size="6">
        </select>
    </div>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="position:absolute;left: 150px;" onclick="setSelectedValues()"/>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
//Function to select multiple values
function getMultipleSelectedValues() {
    //fetch all available options
    var e = document.getElementById("a_groups");
    //fetch all selected options from available group
    var selectedOptions = e.selectedOptions;
    //get the selected group to append the selected options
    var s_select = document.getElementById('s_groups');

    //If items are not selected display alert message
    if (e.selectedOptions.length < 1) {
        alert("Please select atleast one item that need to be added");
    } else {
        //create option elements for selected group
        for (var i = 0; i < e.selectedOptions.length; i++) {
            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.value = selectedOptions[i].value;
            opt.text = selectedOptions[i].text;
            s_select.appendChild(opt);
        }

        //remove option element from available group once they are selected.
        for (var i = 0; i < e.options.length;) {
            if (e.options[i]!=null && e.options[i].selected == true) {
                e.options[i].remove(i);
                i--;
            } else {
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}

//Function to select single value
function getSingleSelectedValue() {
    //fetch all available options
    var e = document.getElementById("a_groups");
    //get the selected group to append the selected options
    var s_select = document.getElementById('s_groups');

    //If more than one option is selected display alert message
    if (e.selectedOptions.length > 1) {
        alert("Please select only one item to be added");
    } else if (e.selectedOptions.length < 1) {
        alert("Please select one item that need to be added");
    } else {
        //add the selected option to selected group
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = e.selectedOptions[0].value;
        opt.text = e.selectedOptions[0].text;
        s_select.appendChild(opt);

        //remove the selected option from available group
        e.selectedOptions[0].remove(0);
    }
}

//Function to de-select single value
function setSingleDeSelectedValue() {
    //fetch all selected options
    var e = document.getElementById("s_groups");
    //get the available group to append the selected option
    var s_select = document.getElementById('a_groups');

    //If more than one option is selected display alert message
    if (e.selectedOptions.length > 1) {
        alert("Please select only one item to be removed");
    } else if (e.selectedOptions.length < 1) {
        alert("Please select one item to be removed");
    } else {
        //add the selected option to available group
        for (var i = 0; i < e.selectedOptions.length; i++) {
            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.value = e.selectedOptions[i].value;
            opt.text = e.selectedOptions[i].text;
            s_select.appendChild(opt);
        }
        //remove the selected option from selected group
        e.selectedOptions[0].remove(0);
    }
}
//Function to de-select multiple values
function setMultipleDeSelectedValue() {
    //fetch all selected options
    var e = document.getElementById("s_groups");
    //get the available group to append the de-selected options
    var s_select = document.getElementById('a_groups');

    //If items are not selected display alert message
    if (e.selectedOptions.length < 1) {
        alert("Please select atleast one item that need to be removed");
    } else {
        //create option elements for available group
        for (var i = 0; i < e.selectedOptions.length; i++) {
            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.value = e.selectedOptions[i].value;
            opt.text = e.selectedOptions[i].text;
            s_select.appendChild(opt);
        }

        //remove the selected options from selected group
        for (var i = 0; i < e.options.length;) {
            if (e.options[i]!=null && e.options[i].selected == true) {
                e.options[i].remove(i);
                i--;
            } else {
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
//Function to set all selected values in s_groups
function setSelectedValues() {
    var e = document.getElementById("s_groups");
    for (var i = 0; i < e.options.length; i++) {
        e.options[i].selected = true;
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Woa, very detail, thanks. I will apply this to my web application.